How to fix SLDS updates in new release, issue for tab icon color
I have following code working perfectly with tab icon color brings up perfectly.
Suddenly after today's release patch it got failed, Any idea to enable tab icon color ?
HTML:
<template>
    <lightning-tabset variant="vertical" class="verticalTabSet">
        <lightning-tab label="Core Settings" icon-name="utility:settings" data-id= 'coreSettingIcon'>
            <div class="tabContent">
                coreSettingIcon
            </div>
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Field MappinfieldMappingIcong" icon-name="utility:link" data-id= ''>
            <div class="tabContent">
                fieldMappingIcon
            </div>
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Rules" value="Rules" icon-name="utility:rules" data-id= 'rulesIcon'>
            <div class="tabContent">
                rulesIcon
            </div>
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Logs" icon-name="utility:edit_form" data-id= 'logsIcon'>
            <div class="tabContent">
                logsIcon
            </div>
        </lightning-tab>
    </lightning-tabset>
</template>

Js:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class HomePageConfig extends LightningElement {

    renderedCallback(){
        this.setTabIconFillColor('verticalTabSet','fieldMappingIcon', 'utility-link', 'darkgreen');
        this.setTabIconFillColor('verticalTabSet','rulesIcon', 'utility-rules', 'firebrick');
        this.setTabIconFillColor('verticalTabSet','logsIcon', 'utility-edit-form', 'royalblue');
    }

    setTabIconFillColor(tabParentClass,tabDataId, iconName, fillColor) {
        let icon  = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id='${tabDataId}']`);
        let iconId = icon.getAttribute("aria-labelledby");
        const styleCss = document.createElement('style');
        styleCss.innerText = ` .${tabParentClass} #${iconId} .slds-icon-${iconName} svg { fill:${fillColor} !important;  } `;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-tabset')?.appendChild(styleCss);
    }
}

I have used this route as stying-hooks are not supported in tabs, let me know if there is a proper approach to fix this permanently.
Known issue- https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ0cmAAC/the-class-attribute-is-not-getting-applied-to-the-content-of-a-lightningtab
